# Change visited link color of notification list by using css doesn't work

Tags: 2010, list, css

I'm trying to change the color of item link in notification list after user clicked it. Here's my css code:

```
.ms-vb a:link {
  color: blue;
}

.ms-vb a:visited {
    color: red;
 }
```

The first part worked perfectly, all the links indeed changed to blue. But after I clicked the link, the color of link remained blue, which is supposed to changed to red.

So, what's the proper way to set up a css to change the color of visited link in notification list?

Comment: Did you try the !important tag? color: red !important;

Comment: @Marco, I tried, it did not work.

Comment: just as a comment many of the link in SharePoint are not an "a" tag they are "span" into an "a" tag, so check that and try to change the color for the inner tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `a:visited` is not supported because of security reason.

It is possible to retrieve a visitor's history by checking for visited links, certain measures have been taken to prevent this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210871/use-jquery-to-select-visited-links